# I am unable to get max function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have the following query:

```
SELECT A.F01 AS F01, P.F31 AS F31, P.F30 AS F30, C.F19 AS F19, C.F38 AS F38
FROM A_TAB A
LEFT OUTER JOIN P_TAB P ON P.F01=A.F01
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_TAB C ON C.F01=A.F01
ORDER By 1;
```

It displays as follows:

```
f01            f31   f30   f19   f38
0000000000001   1   2.99    100 0.50
0000000000002   1   0.10    1   0.05
0000000000002   1   0.10    1   0.05
0000000000003   1   0.20    20  1.00
0000000000003   1   0.20    36  0.35
0000000000004   1   0.30    1   1.00
0000000000005   1   0.60    23  NULL
0000000000005   1   0.60    23  1.25
0000000000006   1   0.90    11  2.50
0000000000006   1   0.90    2   1.00
```

The last two rows has 0000000000006 in coloumn 1 (f01) and has two subsequent values 2.50 and 1.00 in the last column(f38),
I need to get only one row with the maximum value
(max of 2.50 and 1.00)

Please can you help me out, I am getting errors all the time when i use max on the f38 column with group by and have hit a dead end. :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `max()`:

```
SELECT A.F01 AS F01, P.F31 AS F31, P.F30 AS F30, MAX(C.F38) AS F38
FROM A_TAB A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     P_TAB P
     ON P.F01=A.F01 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     C_TAB C
     ON C.F01=A.F01
GROPU BY A.F01, P.F31, P.F30
ORDER By 1;
```

I removed `F19` because you don't say what to do with it.

Comment: It worked but when I add C.F19 as F19 it gets both values for F38

Comment: As I mentioned, you don't say what to do with `F19`.  You can choose `MIN(F19)` or `MAX(F19)` if you want one of the values.

Comment: Anyways I got it working, the problem was that I wasnt, considering all the other columns in group by. Thanks alot!